# Google map API key credential additional methods

Tags: google-maps

I have received a Google Map API Key and it seems to work just fine. Looking on the credential page of the GCP I see there are some alternate methods that I don't see documented anywhere. I have attached a screen shot of the specific page I am referring to, but I was wondering if anyone could give me insight on how to use these methods (OAuth and Service Accounts) or where I might find more documentation.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` and `Service Accounts` may not be needed for Google Maps APIs. You will only need API keys to authenticate Google Maps APIs requests as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices), so I think you can ignore the others.

But to give you an insights, as per the [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication):

- `OAuths 2.0 Client IDs` are used to allow your apps to access other Google Cloud products on behalf of the user.
- `Service Accounts` are accounts that used by an app to make authorized API calls for other Google Cloud products. You can learn more here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts